# POST form data in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, post, form-data, nsmutableurlrequest

I have to pass **form data** in body part. here is postman  **screen short** for better understanding.
**body part**
[image]

**content type**

[image]

here is my code what I had try.

```
    NSString *Accesstoken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",tokenInfo.access_token];

   //    parameter is String object : "user_id=18&deal_id=218"

   //NSDictionary *tmp = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     @"user_id", @"18487",
                     @"deal_id", @"218",
                     nil];
```

//  NSError *errorr;
 //   NSData *postdata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:tmp options:0 error:&errorr];

```
[request setValue:Accesstoken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

// NSData *postData = [parameter dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
```

// [request setHTTPBody:postData];;
   // [request setHTTPBody:[parameter dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   // [request setHTTPBody:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:@{@"user_id":@"18487",@"deal_id":@"218" } options:0 error:nil]];

for above code I am getting http status code : 404 its wrong. and when I try in postman I am getting 401 its perfect I want that. Please help Thanks.

Comment: Instead of `parameter` as you did, try `[request setHTTPBody:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:@{@"user_id":@"18",@"deal_id":@"218" } options:0 error:nil]];`? Also, you hid the address in the top address bar, but not on the left menu (FYI).

Comment: I try but still getting nil response

Answer (score 3):

Just export the request from POSTMAN in objective-C : https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/generate_code_snippets